# citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:61: attempt to call a nil value (upvalue 'fn')

Tags: css, codeigniter, lua, identify, fivem

So the code error is this:
Also, the lua code is used for FiveM-coding, using vRP as main framework.
The error appeals a function that is on vRP, and the caller is a base-function from the artifacts.

Even so, this is the code of the artifact that triggers the error

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtVm3.png)

[How the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLB6J.png)

```
local GetGameTimer = GetGameTimer
local _sbs = Citizen.SubmitBoundaryStart
local coresume, costatus = coroutine.resume, coroutine.status
local debug = debug
local coroutine_close = coroutine.close or (function(c) end) -- 5.3 compatibility
local hadThread = false
local curTime = 0

-- setup msgpack compat
msgpack.set_string('string_compat')
msgpack.set_integer('unsigned')
msgpack.set_array('without_hole')
msgpack.setoption('empty_table_as_array', true)

-- setup json compat
json.version = json._VERSION -- Version compatibility
json.setoption("empty_table_as_array", true)
json.setoption('with_hole', true)

-- temp
local _in = Citizen.InvokeNative

local function FormatStackTrace()
    return _in(`FORMAT_STACK_TRACE` & 0xFFFFFFFF, nil, 0, Citizen.ResultAsString())
end

local function ProfilerEnterScope(scopeName)
    return _in(`PROFILER_ENTER_SCOPE` & 0xFFFFFFFF, scopeName)
end

local function ProfilerExitScope()
    return _in(`PROFILER_EXIT_SCOPE` & 0xFFFFFFFF)
end

local newThreads = {}
local threads = setmetatable({}, {
    -- This circumvents undefined behaviour in "next" (and therefore "pairs")
    __newindex = newThreads,
    -- This is needed for CreateThreadNow to work correctly
    __index = newThreads
})

local boundaryIdx = 1
local runningThread

local function dummyUseBoundary(idx)
    return nil
end

local function getBoundaryFunc(bfn, bid)
    return function(fn, ...)
        local boundary = bid or (boundaryIdx + 1)
        boundaryIdx = boundaryIdx + 1
        
        bfn(boundary, coroutine.running())

        local wrap = function(...)
            dummyUseBoundary(boundary)
            
            local v = table.pack(fn(...))
            return table.unpack(v)
        end
        
        local v = table.pack(wrap(...))
        
        bfn(boundary, nil)
        
        return table.unpack(v)
    end
end
```

Comment: please share text as text. not screenshots of text. otherwise we cannot copy it

Comment: the provided code has less than 61 lines. the error is reported at line 61 of scheduler.lua.  there is an upvalue `fn` in your code but your code does not contain a call to `getBoundaryFunc` nor its return value. in order to find out why `fn` is nil you need to check that

Comment: I've added the whole code, didn't work for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot of your code shows two calls to `getBoundaryFunc`

```
runWithBoundaryStart = getBoundaryFunc(Citizen.SubmitBoundaryStart)
runWithBoundaryEnd = getBoundaryFunc(Citizen.SubmitBoundaryEnd)
```

In order for `fn` to become nil either of this funcions must be called without proving the first parameter.

1. find out wether there are more calls to `getBoundaryFunc`
2. find out if its return values are called with nil instead of the expected function value as first parameter
3. fix that